# How do I use the Google::Apis::SheetsV4::BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest object properly?

Tags: ruby, google-sheets-api

For now I'm just trying to add data to a cell in a Google Sheet using the batch_update_spreadsheet method of the SheetsService class. I know I could use the batch_update_values method for this purpose, but eventually I want to be able to add data to and change the formatting of multiple cells at the same time, which I can't do with that method. When I run the following code, I don't get any errors, but the cell is not updated on the given sheet:

```
cell_data = Sheets::CellData.new(:formatted_value => "Hello World")
row_data = Sheets::RowData.new(:values => [cell_data])
grid_coordinate = Sheets::GridCoordinate.new(:sheet_id => 0, :column_index => 3, :row_index => 5)
update_cells_request = Sheets::UpdateCellsRequest.new(:fields => "formatted_value", :rows => [row_data], :range => grid_coordinate)
request = Sheets::Request.new(:update_cells => update_cells_request)
requests << request
batch_update_spreadsheet_request_object = Sheets::BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest.new(:requests => requests, :include_spreadsheet_in_response => true, :response_include_grid_data => true)
result = $service.batch_update_spreadsheet($spreadsheet_id, batch_update_spreadsheet_request_object)
```

Does anyone have any ideas why this code would not work the way it is intended to?

Comment: It would be nice if I could insert the following code above the code I mentioned before and have everything still work as well:

Comment: cell_color = Sheets::Color.new(:blue => 1, :red => 0, :green => 0)
      cell_format = Sheets::CellFormat.new(:background_color => cell_color)
  cell_data = Sheets::CellData.new(:formatted_value => date_string, :effective_format => cell_format)